# update flot chart with new data from ajax

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, object, flot

I have the following output from php which I am getting from using ajax.

```
AVAILABILITY: "99.26"
BEARER: "3G"
SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_D): "11458800"
SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_N): "84353"
TIMESTAMP: "2015-12-08 14:00"
VENDOR: "Hua"
VF_REGION: "South"
```

Array contains 4325. I am trying to sum `UNAVAILABILITY_D` and `UNAVAILABILITY_N` and group them by `TIMESTAMP`. `TIMESTAMP` is always hourly.

My first function I loop array and convert date to seconds and within each timestamp array I sum up `UNAVAILABILITY_D` and `UNAVAILABILITY_N`.

```
function loopInitial(data){
    console.log(data);
    var n = 0;
    var d = 0;
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        //sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP] = ( typeof sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP] != 'undefined' && sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP] instanceof Array ) ? sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP] : []
        //sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] = ( typeof sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] != 'undefined' && sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] instanceof Array ) ? sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] : []
        //sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] = ( typeof sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] != 'undefined' && sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] instanceof Array ) ? sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] : []
        //sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] += data[i]['SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_N)'];
        //sevenDays_object[data[i].TIMESTAMP]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] += data[i]['SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_D)'];

        var to_seconds = new Date(data[i].TIMESTAMP).getTime() / 1000; // convert date to seconds as string is not sortable in object.
        if( typeof sevenDays_object[to_seconds] == 'undefined' && !(sevenDays_object[to_seconds] instanceof Array) ) { sevenDays_object[to_seconds] = []; }     
        if( typeof sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] == 'undefined' && !(sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] instanceof Array) ) { sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] = [] ;}
        if( typeof sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] == 'undefined' && !(sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] instanceof Array) ) {sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] = []; }
        sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] = +sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] + +data[i]['SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_N)'];
        sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'] = +sevenDays_object[to_seconds]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] + +data[i]['SUM(UNAVAILABILITY_D)'];
    }
    //console.log(sevenDays_object);
    //console.log(sevenDays_object);
    return sevenDays_object;
}
```

I then loop this object to get the correct calculation and create object for flot graph.

```
function calculateAvailability(data){
    //console.log(data);
    var arr = [];
    for (property in data){
        console.log( property ); 
        console.log( data[property] );
        //var d = new Date(property);
        //console.log(d);
        //var s = d.getTime() / 1000;
        //var availability = (Math.round( ( (1 - data[property]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] / data[property]['UNAVAILABILITY_D'])  * 100) * 100)) / 100;
        var availability = Math.round( ((1 - data[property]['UNAVAILABILITY_N'] / data[property]['UNAVAILABILITY_D']) * 100) *100 ) /100;
        //if(property == 1450069200){
            console.log("availability = " + availability);
        //}
        arr.push({0 : property ,1: availability });
    }

    //for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        //console.log(arr[i]);
        //arr[data[i]] = ( typeof arr[data[i]] != 'undefined' && arr[data[i]] instanceof Array ) ? data[i] : []
        //arr[i] = ( typeof arr[i] != 'undefined' && arr[i] instanceof Array ) ? i : []
    //}
    //console.log( "2015/12/11 07:00" + " = " + new Date("2015/12/11 07:00").getTime() / 1000 );
    var y = new Date( 1449817200 * 1000);
    //console.log( y );
    var x = new Date( 1449208800000 * 1000);
    console.log( x );
    console.log( x.getFullYear() );
     ///plot.setData(arr);
     //plot.setupGrid();
     //plot.draw();
    //console.log(arr);

    return arr;
}
```

Problem I have now is the date conversion don't seem to be correct. Below is the calculation data that i have worked out

```
[1449572400,0.68]
[1449576000,29.54]
[1449579600,92.78]
[1449583200,92.96]
[1449586800,66.82]
[1449590400,91.9]
[1449594000,65.98]
[1449597600,68.78]
[1449601200,51.75]
[1449604800,2.47]
[1449608400,91.25]
[1449612000,1.5]
[1449615600,39.19]
[1449619200,72.43]
[1449622800,0.8]
[1449626400,46.81]
[1449630000,68.37]
[1449633600,79.43]
[1449637200,67.18]
[1449640800,2.43]
[1449644400,2.4]
[1449648000,0.6]
[1449651600,0.24]
[1449655200,0.22]
[1449658800,70.17]
[1449662400,57.82]
[1449666000,62.86]
[1449669600,72.58]
[1449673200,0.25]
[1449676800,94.16]
[1449680400,62.4]
[1449684000,2.51]
[1449687600,40.69]
[1449691200,91.54]
[1449694800,2.49]
[1449698400,90.85]
[1449702000,0.92]
[1449705600,41.44]
[1449709200,1]
[1449712800,70.08]
[1449716400,36]
[1449720000,37.89]
[1449723600,0.63]
[1449727200,0.83]
[1449730800,0.65]
[1449734400,74.95]
[1449738000,0.62]
[1449741600,0.43]
[1449745200,0.2]
[1449748800,0.1]
[1449752400,61.95]
[1449756000,71.94]
[1449759600,73.07]
[1449763200,74.87]
[1449766800,32.19]
[1449770400,78.38]
[1449774000,67.64]
[1449777600,88.73]
[1449781200,65.47]
[1449784800,76.68]
[1449788400,35.89]
[1449792000,91.54]
[1449795600,0.61]
[1449799200,90.14]
[1449802800,96.4]
[1449806400,0.62]
[1449810000,0.31]
[1449813600,0.31]
[1449817200,0.31]
[1449820800,1.82]
[1449824400,0.44]
[1449828000,82.85]
[1449831600,39.28]
[1449835200,87.17]
[1449838800,0.21]
[1449842400,59.39]
[1449846000,73.77]
[1449849600,74.69]
[1449853200,63.96]
[1449856800,68.37]
[1449860400,80.92]
[1449864000,94.81]
[1449867600,0.46]
[1449871200,24.99]
[1449874800,0.26]
[1449878400,91.72]
[1449882000,73.82]
[1449885600,70.85]
[1449889200,0.72]
[1449892800,90.59]
[1449896400,2.4]
[1449900000,68.8]
[1449903600,0.37]
[1449907200,41.86]
[1449910800,33.88]
[1449914400,78.3]
[1449918000,1.83]
[1449921600,0.53]
[1449925200,75.03]
[1449928800,35]
[1449932400,0.69]
[1449936000,81.65]
[1449939600,74.92]
[1449943200,82.76]
[1449946800,81.99]
[1449950400,80.27]
[1449954000,0.77]
[1449957600,94.3]
[1449961200,71.93]
[1449964800,75.23]
[1449968400,82.99]
[1449972000,0.42]
[1449975600,2.72]
[1449979200,80.1]
[1449982800,46.92]
[1449986400,0.83]
[1449990000,92.25]
[1449993600,0.38]
[1449997200,69.46]
[1450000800,0.32]
[1450004400,81.72]
[1450008000,38]
[1450011600,81.18]
[1450015200,38.18]
[1450018800,91.65]
[1450022400,93.11]
[1450026000,82.31]
[1450029600,0.43]
[1450033200,84.57]
[1450036800,92.72]
[1450040400,71.68]
[1450044000,2.87]
[1450047600,94.17]
[1450051200,0.42]
[1450054800,82.32]
[1450058400,0.82]
[1450062000,84.66]
[1450065600,0.41]
[1450069200,76.55]
[1450072800,74.01]
[1450076400,84.95]
```

After I removed the `/ 1000` on date calculations to seconds the date works however now I can notice the ordering is not correct.

```
[1449583200000,92.96],
[1449597600000,68.78],
[1449576000000,29.54],
[1449669600000,72.58],
[1449604800000,2.47],
[1449572400000,0.68],
[1449687600000,40.69],
[1449655200000,0.22],
[1449619200000,72.43],
[1449586800000,66.82],
[1449601200000,51.75],
[1449622800000,0.8],
[1449608400000,91.25],
[1449633600000,79.43],
[1449698400000,90.85],
[1449579600000,92.78],
[1449612000000,1.5],
[1449590400000,91.9],
[1449594000000,65.98],
[1449615600000,39.19],
[1449662400000,57.82],
[1449716400000,36],
[1449723600000,0.63],
[1449694800000,2.49],
[1449658800000,70.17],
[1449702000000,0.92],
[1449673200000,0.25],
[1449648000000,0.6],
[1449630000000,68.37],
[1449637200000,67.18],
[1449640800000,2.43],
[1449712800000,70.08],
[1449810000000,0.31],
[1449644400000,2.4],
[1449813600000,0.31],
[1449806400000,0.62],
[1449748800000,0.1],
[1449756000000,71.94],
[1449738000000,0.62],
[1449781200000,65.47],
[1449795600000,0.61],
[1449763200000,74.87],
[1449799200000,90.14],
[1449709200000,1],
[1449727200000,0.83],
[1449626400000,46.81],
[1449741600000,0.43],
[1449766800000,32.19],
[1449730800000,0.65],
[1449676800000,94.16],
[1449680400000,62.4],
[1449774000000,67.64],
[1449684000000,2.51],
[1449745200000,0.2],
[1449734400000,74.95],
[1449867600000,0.46],
[1449838800000,0.21],
[1449720000000,37.89],
[1449824400000,0.44],
[1449666000000,62.86],
[1449820800000,1.82],
[1449846000000,73.77],
[1449752400000,61.95],
[1449885600000,70.85],
[1449705600000,41.44],
[1449849600000,74.69],
[1449860400000,80.92],
[1449946800000,81.99],
[1449828000000,82.85],
[1449943200000,82.76],
[1449900000000,68.8],
[1449802800000,96.4],
[1449889200000,0.72],
[1449896400000,2.4],
[1449882000000,73.82],
[1449864000000,94.81],
[1449831600000,39.28],
[1449835200000,87.17],
[1449759600000,73.07],
[1449990000000,92.25],
[1450004400000,81.72],
[1450008000000,38],
[1449878400000,91.72],
[1450011600000,81.18],
[1449792000000,91.54],
[1449925200000,75.03],
[1449993600000,0.38],
[1449997200000,69.46],
[1449972000000,0.42],
[1449871200000,24.99],
[1449856800000,68.37],
[1449975600000,2.72],
[1449853200000,63.96],
[1449928800000,35],
[1449777600000,88.73],
[1449986400000,0.83],
[1449918000000,1.83],
[1449910800000,33.88],
[1449914400000,78.3],
[1449842400000,59.39],
[1449982800000,46.92],
[1449979200000,80.1],
[1449921600000,0.53],
[1449950400000,80.27],
[1449964800000,75.23],
[1450022400000,93.11],
[1450033200000,84.57],
[1449784800000,76.68],
[1449788400000,35.89],
[1449770400000,78.38],
[1449892800000,90.59],
[1449903600000,0.37],
[1449907200000,41.86],
[1449961200000,71.93],
[1450026000000,82.31],
[1449874800000,0.26],
[1449932400000,0.69],
[1450036800000,92.72],
[1450040400000,71.68],
[1450047600000,94.17],
[1449968400000,82.99],
[1450051200000,0.42],
[1450018800000,91.65],
[1450029600000,0.43],
[1450058400000,0.82],
[1449957600000,94.3],
[1449936000000,81.65],
[1450000800000,0.32],
[1450044000000,2.87],
[1450015200000,38.18],
[1449939600000,74.92],
[1450069200000,76.55],
[1450062000000,84.66],
[1450065600000,0.41],
[1450076400000,84.95],
[1449954000000,0.77],
[1450054800000,82.32],
[1449651600000,0.24],
[1449691200000,91.54],
[1449817200000,0.31],
[1450072800000,74.01],
```

UPDATE

I have fixed the ordering in php side. I have solved flot plotting with correct day and month showing on x-axis

```
var to_seconds = moment(data[i].TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A').unix() * 1000;
```

Problem I have now is if i convert `to_seconds` back to date time format, the month and day are correct but not the year.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you' re asking. Both 1449208800000 and 1449817200 convert to the correct date. To which date do you expect them to convert? One strange thing in your code is you using`new Date(property+":00")`. Shouldn't that be `new Date(data[property]+":00")`?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: UPDATE: I would change the line `var s = d.getTime() / 1000;` to just `var s = property / 1000` and before `setData` first sort the array by property value.

Comment: On second thought, I think your first problem is that you have a date string from php in format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM and you want to pass that to Javascript. That doesn't work. Read http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp. You will find that you have a mix between using the Javascript Short Date format (YYYY/MM/DD) and the ISO format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS). It is best to convert the input in php to give you (milli)seconds to start with. Or if you don't have access to the input, try converting the date string to the ISO format by replacing / with -.

Comment: @user2288476 it is an oracle query which i have changed the select to `TO_CHAR (TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi') TIMESTAMP` as you have suggested.The `property` is a string value of datetime, does it not need it to be converted to secs first?

Comment: Your question (and your code) is all over the place. Try to reduce it to the actual problem. The principal code works fine (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3mka76n/)). And don't use objects instead of arrays when the order of the parts is important, [order of properties in objects is not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/2610249).

Comment: (The timestamps in your calculation data have to be multiplied by 1000.) Also, check your min / max values on the y axis for the chart, the new values are outside of the range you posted in your original question. Use [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort your data.

Comment: in loop initial I have done `sevenDays_object.sort()`, not working for me. updated min/max values. removed `ticksize` on `x-axis`

Comment: `sort()` doesn't work on objects, only arrays. And if the parts are not simple data types (string, number ...) you need to use the compare function.

Comment: @ bonez Yes it has to be converted to seconds. That's why you need the right string format for Javscript to convert it to seconds. I would so that in php. Also because using Javascript's Date function might change the date according to locale of the browser.But I think you figured that part out already.

Comment: @user2288476 I managed to convert to ms for flot graph by `*1000`, however if you convert this value to string format it shows year is 4xxxxx and not 2015. how do i solve this?

Comment: @Raidri updated question